# Unable to get data from unzipped file

Tags: macos, zip, unzip

I have a file on MacOS that I extracted from a ZIP archive that appears to have 113020 bytes or zero bytes depending on who's asking. So far I can't open it.
The Finder's **GetInfo** function reports that the file has 113020 bytes in it. **Stuffit Archive Manager** also says 110.5 KB compressed to 22.2 KB. But the **ls** command in Terminal says it has 0 bytes. **Hex Fiend** shows 0 bytes. **BBEdit** won't do a hex dump. The **cat** command in Terminal copies 0 bytes. The **unzip** command in Terminal extracts it as an empty file. I've never seen anything quite like it.
The original ZIP file is confidential, so I can't post it anywhere. Several of the files in the ZIP archive I started with act the same. The only other visible oddity I've found is that the file's name contains quotation marks and forward slashes, but renaming the file to a strictly alphabetic string didn't help.
I don't know any way to get either the unzip command or **Stuffit Extractor** to unzip the file to a different name, and I'm just clutching at straws thinking that the name has anything to do with its dual filesize nature. This file's size is like Schröedinger's cat: It is simultaneously 0 bytes and 113020 bytes. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Stuffit is usually pretty good with 'awkward' files, but maybe try [BetterZip](https://macitbetter.com), which can show the contents of a zip like a folder before unarchiving. You can also unzip individual components. Maybe it could give a clearer view of what's going on.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the idea; I'll try it. I did try Stuffit Archive Manager, which supports looking thru the archive like a directory and extracting individual files. It extracted the problem file as zero-length even though it showed 110.5 KB size inside the archive.

Comment: @Tetsujin Update: I tried BetterZip and got the same weird results. BetterZip showed the selected problem file as 0 bytes in its directory-like listing but showed 113140 bytes on the info panel at the right side. It extracted the file as 0 bytes. Nice try, but still no luck.

Comment: I'd get whoever is making these to start using RAR/PAR, or even .dmg - at least they checksum